# Highcharts Drilldown Y axis min and max

Tags: highcharts, drilldown

Can anybody give an example of `drilldown` chart that has min and max for the Y axis labels? Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-drilldown/) of the example from the [Highcharts website](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-drilldown/).

I have been trying to figure out how to set a min and max for the Y axis labels. So for example instead of starting at 0 i would like to start at 88.

Answer (score 0):

To get the desired result - for example, start yAxis values at 88, you should use this settings:

```
new Highcharts.Chart({
    ....
    yAxis: {
        min: 88,
        startOnTick: false // To prevent rounding of this value.
    },
    ....
});
```

Hope this helps.